# to count the occurrence of one string in other string in python

Tags: python, string

If this is the first string : `ABCD`

if this is the second string: `ABCD is ABCD`

I want to count the occurrence of first string in the second string and that too in python. How can I do that?I'm new to python, so facing some problems. Can anyone tell me the solution or provide the code for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count):

```
>>> str1 = "ABCD"
>>> str2 = "ABCD is ABCD"
>>> str2.count(str1)
2
```

Comment: Thanks it worked , The solution was so simple, it skipped from my mind that I can use count :)

Comment: @POOJAGUPTA yes it was simple. You can accept the solution if it worked for you.

Comment: If str1 = "AA" and str2 = "AAAA" then the output is 2 if count() is used. But, it is not correct, right ?

I think the correct output is 3. Because, 
1st substring is index 0 & index 1 together. 
2nd substring is index 1 & index 2 together. 
3rd substring is index 2 & index 3.

So, the correct output is 3, right ? Please clarify.

Comment: @RajKumarRampelli Nop, 2 is the correct output in that case as it *returns the number of non-overlapping occurrences*. To get the overlapping count you can use regex: `len(re.findall('(?=AA)', 'AAAA')) == 3`.

Comment: The re.findall('(?=AA)', 'AAAA') expression return the list [' ', ' ', ' '] and which is of length 3. 



When I used regex 'AA' instead of '(?=AA)' then the output is ['AA', 'AA'].

My query is why the output doesn't contain substrings 'AA' when regex '(?=AA)' used ? also, what is the use of '?=' ?

Comment: @RajKumarRampelli  `?=` means [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in regex, it is not supposed capture any character. The regex simply means if the next two characters from the current position are `AA` then return the match(note that in this case there's nothing before `'(?=AA)'`, hence empty strings are returned). Please go through a regex tutorial for more details.